# Browsing with OPC Foundation Java Stack

Tags: java, opc-ua

i hope someone can help me.

I'm writing a OPC-UA client in java and I can browse only the first node.

```
 ResponseHeader=ResponseHeader
    Timestamp=05/11/18 09:38:42.3063457 GMT
    RequestHandle=0
    ServiceResult=GOOD (0x00000000) ""
    ServiceDiagnostics=Diagnostic Info: 

    StringTable=class java.lang.String[0]
    AdditionalHeader=null
  Results=class org.opcfoundation.ua.core.BrowseResult[1]
    [0]=BrowseResult
    StatusCode=GOOD (0x00000000) ""
    ContinuationPoint=null
    References=class org.opcfoundation.ua.core.ReferenceDescription[2]
      [0]=ReferenceDescription
      ReferenceTypeId=i=35
      IsForward=true
      NodeId=nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2253
      BrowseName=Server
      DisplayName=Server
      NodeClass=NodeClass
        value=1
        name=Object
        ordinal=1
      TypeDefinition=nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2004
      [1]=ReferenceDescription
      ReferenceTypeId=i=35
      IsForward=true
      NodeId=ns=2;s=WRT
      BrowseName=2:WRT
      DisplayName=WRT
      NodeClass=NodeClass
        value=1
        name=Object
        ordinal=1
      TypeDefinition=nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=58
  DiagnosticInfos=class org.opcfoundation.ua.builtintypes.DiagnosticInfo[0]
```

I would see the others arms of the tree. But the second browsing return null.

```
2018-05-11 11:22:56,190 [Component Resolve Thread (Bundle 6)] DEBUG c.a.o.u.ClientService - i = 0 x= 0
2018-05-11 11:22:56,191 [Component Resolve Thread (Bundle 6)] DEBUG c.a.o.u.ClientService - BrowseName   Server
2018-05-11 11:22:56,191 [Component Resolve Thread (Bundle 6)] DEBUG c.a.o.u.ClientService - NodeId       nsu=http%3A%2F%2Fopcfoundation.org%2FUA%2F;i=2253
2018-05-11 11:22:56,191 [Component Resolve Thread (Bundle 6)] DEBUG c.a.o.u.ClientService - DisplayName  Server
2018-05-11 11:22:56,192 [Component Resolve Thread (Bundle 6)] DEBUG c.a.o.u.ClientService - BrowseResponse
  ResponseHeader=ResponseHeader
    Timestamp=05/11/18 09:22:56.1916234 GMT
    RequestHandle=0
    ServiceResult=GOOD (0x00000000) ""
    ServiceDiagnostics=Diagnostic Info: 

    StringTable=class java.lang.String[0]
    AdditionalHeader=null
  Results=class org.opcfoundation.ua.core.BrowseResult[1]
    [0]=BrowseResult
    StatusCode=GOOD (0x00000000) ""
    ContinuationPoint=null
    References=class org.opcfoundation.ua.core.ReferenceDescription[0]
  DiagnosticInfos=class org.opcfoundation.ua.builtintypes.DiagnosticInfo[0]

2018-05-11 11:22:56,192 [Component Resolve Thread (Bundle 6)] DEBUG c.a.o.u.ClientService - i = 0 x= 1
2018-05-11 11:22:56,192 [Component Resolve Thread (Bundle 6)] DEBUG c.a.o.u.ClientService - BrowseName   2:WRT
2018-05-11 11:22:56,192 [Component Resolve Thread (Bundle 6)] DEBUG c.a.o.u.ClientService - NodeId       ns=2;s=WRT
2018-05-11 11:22:56,192 [Component Resolve Thread (Bundle 6)] DEBUG c.a.o.u.ClientService - DisplayName  WRT
2018-05-11 11:22:56,193 [Component Resolve Thread (Bundle 6)] DEBUG c.a.o.u.ClientService - BrowseResponse
  ResponseHeader=ResponseHeader
    Timestamp=05/11/18 09:22:56.1931274 GMT
    RequestHandle=0
    ServiceResult=GOOD (0x00000000) ""
    ServiceDiagnostics=Diagnostic Info: 

    StringTable=class java.lang.String[0]
    AdditionalHeader=null
  Results=class org.opcfoundation.ua.core.BrowseResult[1]
    [0]=BrowseResult
    StatusCode=GOOD (0x00000000) ""
    ContinuationPoint=null
    References=class org.opcfoundation.ua.core.ReferenceDescription[0]
  DiagnosticInfos=class org.opcfoundation.ua.builtintypes.DiagnosticInfo[0]
```

here my code to browse for 2 levels:

```
public void browse(NodeId nodeId) throws ServiceFaultException, ServiceResultException {
    BrowseDescription browse = new BrowseDescription();

    browse.setNodeId(nodeId);
    browse.setBrowseDirection(BrowseDirection.Forward);
    browse.setIncludeSubtypes(true);
    browse.setNodeClassMask(NodeClass.Object, NodeClass.Variable, NodeClass.View);
    browse.setResultMask(BrowseResultMask.All);
    BrowseResponse browseResponse = null;

    int k = 1;
    try {
        browseResponse = mySession.Browse(null, null, null, browse);
        logger.debug(browseResponse.toString());
    } catch (ServiceResultException e) {
        logger.error("Exception", e);
    }


    BrowseResult[] browseResult = browseResponse.getResults();

    for (int i = 0; i < browseResult.length; i++) {
        ReferenceDescription[] referenceDescription = browseResult[i].getReferences();

        for (int x = 0; x < referenceDescription.length; x++) {
            logger.debug("i = " + i + " x= " + x);
            logger.debug("BrowseName   " + referenceDescription[x].getBrowseName());
            logger.debug("NodeId       " + referenceDescription[x].getNodeId());
            logger.debug("DisplayName  " + referenceDescription[x].getDisplayName());


            BrowseDescription browse1 = new BrowseDescription();
            browse1.setNodeId(referenceDescription[x].getReferenceTypeId().ID);
            browse1.setBrowseDirection(BrowseDirection.Forward);
            browse1.setIncludeSubtypes(true);
            browse1.setReferenceTypeId(referenceDescription[x].getReferenceTypeId().ID);
            browse1.setNodeClassMask(NodeClass.Object, NodeClass.Variable, NodeClass.View, NodeClass.Method, NodeClass.ObjectType, NodeClass.VariableType, NodeClass.ReferenceType, NodeClass.DataType);
            browse1.setResultMask(BrowseResultMask.All);
            BrowseResponse browseResponse1 = null;

            try {
                browseResponse1 = mySession.Browse(null, null, null, browse1);

                if (browseResponse1 != null) {
                    logger.debug(browseResponse1.toString());
                }
            } catch (ServiceResultException e) {

                logger.error("Exception", e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Another client has shown others folders after WRT forlder.

Answer (score 0):

> `browse1.setNodeId(referenceDescription[x].getReferenceTypeId().ID);`

This is certainly not what you want. You should be browsing `referenceDescription[x].getNodeId()` in your subsequent browses.

Comment: i tryed with browse1.setNodeId( referenceDescription[x].getNodeId().ID); and i have the same result

Comment: Also, you are limiting the referenceTypes unnecessarily for the second browse. You can remove this: 'browse1.setReferenceTypeId(referenceDescription[x].getReferenceTypeId().ID);'

Comment: And don't use '...getNodeId().ID' Just '...getNodeId()'

Comment: browse1.setNodeId( ..) requires a NodeId but referenceDescription[x].getNodeId() returnes the ExpandedNodeId This is why i used:  browse1.setNodeId( referenceDescription[x].getNodeId().ID);

Comment: You need to convert the `ExpandedNodeId` to a `NodeId`, getting the static ID field is *not* what you want, and it's not doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need a NamespaceTable to do the conversion properly. Use

```
NamespaceTable table = NamespaceTable.getDefaultInstance();
browse1.setNodeId(table.toNodeId(referenceDescription[x].getNodeId()));
```

as reported here https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Java/issues/140